# is it possible to check in html that internet is connected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a webview. My apps displaying my folder link when internet connection is off.

Is it possible to check in html that internet is connected/not connected and displayed manual messages ? i want to hidden error in mobile browser like as.

```
The webpage at http://www.example.com could not be loaded as :
net:: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Comment: Your question specifically states "in HTML", but you have included both the JavaScript and jQuery tags. Are you asking if it is possible in an HTML *only* solution, or in a solution that uses JavaScript?

Comment: Are you loading this from a `file://` URL? If not, does not the base internet connection have to exist just for the user to get your HTML from your server?  Are you asking to test internet connectivity in general, or that you are able to load a specific resource from a specific domain?

Comment: in html + javascript

Comment: i have a specific domain .

Comment: You really need to take some time and read [ask]. Question is far too vague and no code is provided that would trigger that error

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language, So no, You can't. I also don't really get what you are trying to ask. people can't connect to your website without internet.

Comment: Actually it is possible to use a site offline also

Comment: i am new comer in stack overflow. so, my question is not formatted in proper format.